# How NUMBER columns in Oracle deal with numbers exceeding their precision or scale

Tags: oracle

Assuming I have the following column in my DB:

```
value NUMBER(12,3)
```

What will happen if I will try to store a decimal that exceeds the defined scale? 1234.56789

Will I get an error that the scale is exceeded, or will the value be rounded to 3 decimals and stored?

Also, Is it a good practice to let the database do the rounding? Or should that rather be done in the code?

Comment: [It's pretty easy to test and find out...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b5edb2d4d478080c9dd374df77d9c819)

Answer (score 1):

It will be rounded. In your particular example it will be 1234.568 .

[For reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm):

> When you define a NUMBER variable, you can specify its precision (p)
> and scale (s) so that it is sufficiently, but not unnecessarily,
> large. Precision is the number of significant digits. Scale can be
> positive or negative. Positive scale identifies the number of digits
> to the right of the decimal point; negative scale identifies the
> number of digits to the left of the decimal point that can be rounded
> up or down.
>
> The NUMBER data type is supported by Oracle Database standard
> libraries and operates the same way as it does in SQL. It is used for
> dimensions and surrogates when a text or INTEGER data type is not
> appropriate. It is typically assigned to variables that are not used
> for calculations (like forecasts and aggregations), and it is used for
> variables that must match the rounding behavior of the database or
> require a high degree of precision.

Comment: Is it a good practice to let the database do the scaling? Or should that rather be done in the code?

Comment: It's good to have types that match the data type exactly so that you're not losing precission. If you need let's say 6-7 digits after the decimal dot I would recommend prescaling it with a multiplier and keeping the multiplier 100, 1000, 10000 etc in a separate column and then use both in calculations to keep maximum precision, but this is up to the use case.